# set owner of Windows Form that exist in ClassLibrary c#

Tags: c#, winforms, class-library

I have ClassLibrary that have a `Windows Form` named `LookUpBox`. I want to Call `LookUpBox` from my application and set my application as owner of that and do it as blow:

```
LookUpBox foo = new LookUpBox();
foo.Owner = this;
foo.ShowDialog();
```

But when Run my application and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> I see 2 form like :

[image: Alt_Enter Window]

I excepted with set of `Owner` of the `foo`, I see single Window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Anybody know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe set `foo.ShowInTaskbar = False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Window.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> When you open a child window by calling ShowDialog, you should also set the Owner property of the child window. If you don't, then your users won't be able to restore both child window and parent window by pressing the task bar button. Instead, pressing the task bar button will yield a list of windows, including both child and parent window, for them to select; only the selected window is restored.

[Form.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> When a form is owned by another form, it is closed or hidden with the owner form. For example, consider a form named Form2 that is owned by a form named Form1. If Form1 is closed or minimized, Form2 is also closed or hidden.Owned forms are also never displayed behind their owner form. You can use owned forms for windows such as find and replace windows, which should not disappear when the owner form is selected. To determine the forms that are owned by a parent form, use the OwnedForms property.

So what you need to do is to explicitly set `foo.ShowInTaskbar = False` to keep it hidden from taskbar